# PHP Regex display issue

Tags: php, regex, drupal, preg-replace

I'm trying to create a field for sorting book titles which strips the leading "A, An, The" and appends it to the strong after a comma and a space.  Thus "The Road" would become "Road, The"

Sounds simple, but there's something in the code below which causes IE (no other browsers) to spit out a huge block of gibberish.

```
 $node_field[0]['value'] = preg_replace(
     '/^(A|An|The|a|an|the) (.*)/', 
     "$2\x00,$1",
     $node->title
 );
```

Comment: Any reason you're putting a null (`\x00`) in there? That's a highly suspicious character when it comes to dumping strings.

Comment: drop the \x00 just use a normal space, \x00 is a null

Comment: What does the gibberish look like?  Can I get get a copy/paste?

Comment: If this is an IE-only issue, shouldn't it have an IE tag?

Comment: Wow - thx for incredibly fast response

Comment: fixed with: `$node_field[0]['value'] = preg_replace('/^(A|An|The|a|an|the) (.*)/',"$2, $1",$node->title);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use something more like

```
$node_field[0]['value'] = preg_replace(
 '/^(A|An|The) (.*)/i', 
 "$2, $1",
 $node->title
);
```

If I understand correctly, which should change any "A ...", "An ..." or "The ..." to "..., A", "..., An" and "..., The", respectively.

The i after the slash in the Regex pattern makes it case-insensitive, which should catch all versions of A, An, or The.